# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SECHEME

Tags: webview

I have a vehicle tracking system that I converted to a mobile application using a webpage and it works normally. The problem lies when I click on the location coordinates to go to the location of the vehicle.
thank you

I'm not a developer so I didn't do anything. I tried searching YouTub